# Extracting a Part of URL string in jmeter JSON response

Tags: json, url, jmeter

I have the following JSON response to my request in JMeter:

```
{
"response":
 {"info": 
{"success":"1",
"ticket":"http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/?t=aZCcbzidJJKfFgrkk1RYPH0zHTl+MtTuoGeiUw0hEw48nLZUoPrfntO29VV2daEiR3cPbu25/Xf2a3Q1UMZs1tG2BeMKvA0tCrq9+e3dTrWZ0Z1yTrWlkWEbAwmvRwAfMdoX+vDfKd30hW9CBVpyUsA==&uniqueID=dGdck61pZFhGwMJr0cAHzNruDU6ItF1s&dev=1696661"}}}
```

I want to break my url into 3 parts extract and themin 3 different regex variables:
The value folllowing http://43.252.88.109:4006/BracketICT/?
 i.e.

```
t=aZCcbzidJJKfFgrkk1RYPH0zHTl+MtTuoGeiUw0hEw48nLZUoPrfntO29VV2daEiR3cPbu25/Xf2a3Q1UMZs1tG2BeMKvA0tCrq9+e3dTrWZ0Z1yTrWlkWEbAwmvRwAfMdoX+vDfKd30hW9CBVpyUsA==
```

then the value following uniqueID i.e

```
=dGdck61pZFhGwMJr0cAHzNruDU6ItF1s
```

and the value in dev

How this can be done using Regular expression extractor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression in 3 separate extractors:

```
t=([^&]+)
uniqueID=([^&]+)
dev=([^"]+)
```

If you want also the = sign to be included move it inside brackets

You are searching for all characters different than & (or "), which marks the end of the string

Comment: Could you please explain me what does ([^&]+) and ([^"]+) signify? I am not a pro in regex extractors. all i know is (.+?) sign .

Comment: @Radhika you are searching for all characters different than & (or "), which marks the end of the string

Comment: thanks and in order to include = sign do we write like this? t(=[^&]+)

Comment: @Radhika yes, the brackets holds the value you want

Comment: Hi I need to extract 7 and the value a55a865f-31a9-41bd-929c-9563f2808969 from the expression 7@@a55a865f-31a9-41bd-929c-9563f2808969@@Running TestCases@@ where both the values are dynamic. How can it be done?